# Sticky Requests for K8 hostname based on primary key (modulo routing)

Tags: kubernetes, devops

Is it possible to configure k8 so that based on some data in a request it is always routed to the same hostname?

Perhaps something using stateful sets? Can we do a modulo based routing so that a request like 
POST /myroute
{
  _id : 1
}

will always go to one hostname,

and a request like

POST /myroute
{
  _id : 2
}
will always go to another??

Or is there away so that each host can ignore requests based on the payload. This is a pretty standard routing method, similar to a distributed hash table.

Sorry if I'm not explaining this well. But does anyone have any example of this type of k8 configuration?

Comment: Standard implementation of Service resource can't do it.
But you can use ingress with HAproxy,Nginx,Traefik, and configure them.

Comment: Out of interest - what is your reason for requiring this type of routing?

Answer (score 0):

- You can use [vulcand](https://github.com/zekizeki/vulcaningress) as [Ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).It has very good [routing-language](http://vulcand.github.io/proxy.html#routing-language)
- Also [nginx plus](https://www.nginx.com/blog/load-balancing-kubernetes-services-nginx-plus/) as Ingress can be a solution